Proof of tweedies formula on estimator
I 've been reading this paper and in the appendix says that:

$D_\sigma(z) = \mathbb{E}[x|z] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}x p_{x|z}(x|z) \ dx$

can be compactly expresses as:

$D_\sigma(z) = z - \sigma^2\nabla h_\sigma (z)$, where $h_\sigma(z)=-log(p_z(z))$

This can be obtained by differentiating $D_\sigma(z)$ and using the expression for the probability distribution

$p_z(z)=(p_x \circledast \phi_\sigma)(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi_\sigma (z-x) p_x(x)\ dx$,  where $\phi_\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma)^\frac{n}{2}} exp(-\frac{\| x\|^2}{2\sigma^2})$

I cant seem to get around the proof by differentiation. Any insights?

$D_\sigma(z) = \int_\mathbb{R^n} x p_{x|z}(x|z)\ dx = \int_\mathbb{R^n} x p_{z|x}(z|x)\frac{p_x(x)}{p_z(z)}\ dx$
$\nabla p(z|x) = \nabla \phi_\sigma(z-x)=-\frac{z-x}{\sigma^2} \phi_\sigma(z-x)$
$\nabla p_z(z) = -\int_\mathbb{R^n} \frac{z-x}{\sigma^2}\phi_\sigma(z-x)\ dx$.

Therefore,

$\nabla D_\sigma(z) = -\frac{1}{p_z(z)} \big( \int_\mathbb{R^n} xp_x(x)\frac{z-x}{\sigma^2}\phi_\sigma(z-x) \ dx - \int_\mathbb{R^n} xp_x(x)\phi_\sigma(z-x)p_{z|x}(z|x)\frac{\nabla p_z(z)}{p_z(z)} \ dx \big)$ 
$\nabla D_\sigma(z)= -\frac{1}{p_z(z)} \big( \int_\mathbb{R^n} xp_x(x)\frac{z-x}{\sigma^2}\phi_\sigma(z-x) \ dx + \int_\mathbb{R^n} xp_z(z)\phi_\sigma(z-x)p_{x|z}(x|z)\nabla h_\sigma(z) \ dx\big)$

